# Solving Responsive Web Design of a Netflix clone with media Queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Hi this is my first question. I was making a landing page clone of Netflix for a project, when I got stuck for the first time with the responsiveness of the page.
Here is the Netflix animated cards container, at 949px it goes flex column and it keeps the text in line, and the media gets larger. For some reason I can't get it to work, even copying the site settings and units. [949px responsiveness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2sUe.png)

Same thing at 549px [549px responsiveness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usKIW.png)

Here's my code for the html and css:

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    direction: ltr;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1450px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1449px)
{
    .cards {
        padding: 70px 45px;
    }
}

.cards {
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #222;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 50px 5%;
    position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards .animated-cards-container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

.animated-cards .animated-cards-container {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .animated-cards-text {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

.animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .animated-cards-text {
    margin: -2% 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards .animated-cards-text {
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.animated-cards .animated-cards-text {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 3rem 0 0;
    width: 52%;
    z-index: 3;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px)
{
    .animated-cards-title {
        font-size: 1.625rem;
    }
    
}

.animated-cards-title {
    font-size: 3.125rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 27px;
    margin: 0 0 0.4em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px)
{
    .animated-cards-sub, .animated-cards-text {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
    }
}

.animated-cards-sub, .animated-cards-text {
    font-size: 1.625rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards .animated-cards-media {
        margin-top: 1em;
        max-width: 600px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.animated-cards .animated-cards-media {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 48%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .media-container {
        margin: -5% 0 0;
    }
}

.animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .media-container {
    margin: -5% -10% 0 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards .media-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

.animated-cards .media-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .animated-cards-img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

img {
    border: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .animated-cards-video-container {
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    max-height: 47%;
    max-width: 63%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 34%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 100%;
}

.animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .animated-cards-video  {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

audio, canvas, progress, video {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.animated-cards.flipped .animated-cards-container {
    flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards.flipped .animated-cards-container {
        flex-flow: column;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards.flipped .animated-cards-container .animated-cards-text {
        padding: 0;
    }
}

.animated-cards.flipped .animated-cards-container .animated-cards-text {
    padding: 0 0 0 3rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cards animated-cards guarda-ovunque">
        <div class="animated-cards-container">
            <div class="animated-cards-text">
                <h2 class="animated-cards-title">Guarda Netflix ovunque.</h2>
                <h3 class="animated-cards-sub">Cellulare, tablet, laptop e TV: scegli tu cosa usare per guardare in streaming film e serie TV senza limiti e senza spendere di più.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="animated-cards-media">
                <div class="media-container">
                    <img src="https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/acquisition/ourStory/fuji/desktop/device-pile.png" alt="" class="animated-cards-img">
                    <div class="animated-cards-video-container">
                        <video class="animated-cards-video" autoplay="" playsinline="" muted="" loop=""><source src="https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/acquisition/ourStory/fuji/desktop/video-devices.m4v" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cards animated-cards bambini flipped">
        <div class="animated-cards-container">
            <div class="animated-cards-text">
                <h2 class="animated-cards-title">Crea profili per i bambini.</h2>
                <h3 class="animated-cards-sub">I bambini scoprono nuove avventure in compagnia dei loro personaggi preferiti in uno spazio tutto loro già incluso nel tuo abbonamento.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="animated-cards-media">
                <div class="media-container">
                    <img alt="" class="our-story-card-img" src="https://occ-0-728-2581.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/19OhWN2dO19C9txTON9tvTFtefw/AAAABUNsZVszA3HGW04LpkU1tiYnMIoqpcN6YbGSXu5OXQrvWLP1tn7Tee0YM-dJfCazJNwBKnR35ZoqbjE7gTezX57yHz57zixtKS1g.png?r=dda">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are your media queries?

Comment: Didn't add them since they don't work :( but it they are:                                                    @media only screen and (max-width: 349px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards .animated-cards-container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

Comment: Nothing else is working

Comment: Can you update the snippet including the media queries?

Comment: add media query so we can test and answer

Comment: just updated them

Answer (score 0):

If by "not working" you mean that the column is too narrow on smaller screens, just change `width` to `100%` (or any other desired value)  for `.animated-cards .animated-cards-text` inside the media queries:

(you might also want to change the `padding` settings in the media queries to avoid the current offset from the center axis)

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    direction: ltr;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1450px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1449px)
{
    .cards {
        padding: 70px 45px;
    }
}

.cards {
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #222;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 50px 5%;
    position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), 
       only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards .animated-cards-container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

}

.animated-cards .animated-cards-container {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .animated-cards-text {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

.animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .animated-cards-text {
    margin: -2% 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards .animated-cards-text {
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.animated-cards .animated-cards-text {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 3rem 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px)
{
    .animated-cards-title {
        font-size: 1.625rem;
    }
    
}

.animated-cards-title {
    font-size: 3.125rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 27px;
    margin: 0 0 0.4em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px)
{
    .animated-cards-sub, .animated-cards-text {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
    }
}

.animated-cards-sub, .animated-cards-text {
    font-size: 1.625rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards .animated-cards-media {
        margin-top: 1em;
        max-width: 600px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.animated-cards .animated-cards-media {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 48%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .media-container {
        margin: -5% 0 0;
    }
}

.animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .media-container {
    margin: -5% -10% 0 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards .media-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

.animated-cards .media-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .animated-cards-img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

img {
    border: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .animated-cards-video-container {
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    max-height: 47%;
    max-width: 63%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 34%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 100%;
}

.animated-cards.guarda-ovunque .animated-cards-video  {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

audio, canvas, progress, video {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.animated-cards.flipped .animated-cards-container {
    flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards.flipped .animated-cards-container {
        flex-flow: column;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 349px), only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 399px), only screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 549px), only screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 949px)
{
    .animated-cards.flipped .animated-cards-container .animated-cards-text {
        padding: 0;
    }
}

.animated-cards.flipped .animated-cards-container .animated-cards-text {
    padding: 0 0 0 3rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cards animated-cards guarda-ovunque">
        <div class="animated-cards-container">
            <div class="animated-cards-text">
                <h2 class="animated-cards-title">Guarda Netflix ovunque.</h2>
                <h3 class="animated-cards-sub">Cellulare, tablet, laptop e TV: scegli tu cosa usare per guardare in streaming film e serie TV senza limiti e senza spendere di più.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="animated-cards-media">
                <div class="media-container">
                    <img src="https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/acquisition/ourStory/fuji/desktop/device-pile.png" alt="" class="animated-cards-img">
                    <div class="animated-cards-video-container">
                        <video class="animated-cards-video" autoplay="" playsinline="" muted="" loop=""><source src="https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/acquisition/ourStory/fuji/desktop/video-devices.m4v" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cards animated-cards bambini flipped">
        <div class="animated-cards-container">
            <div class="animated-cards-text">
                <h2 class="animated-cards-title">Crea profili per i bambini.</h2>
                <h3 class="animated-cards-sub">I bambini scoprono nuove avventure in compagnia dei loro personaggi preferiti in uno spazio tutto loro già incluso nel tuo abbonamento.</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="animated-cards-media">
                <div class="media-container">
                    <img alt="" class="our-story-card-img" src="https://occ-0-728-2581.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v6/19OhWN2dO19C9txTON9tvTFtefw/AAAABUNsZVszA3HGW04LpkU1tiYnMIoqpcN6YbGSXu5OXQrvWLP1tn7Tee0YM-dJfCazJNwBKnR35ZoqbjE7gTezX57yHz57zixtKS1g.png?r=dda">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By not working I mean the text expand on new lines instead of staying in line and getting smaller, the images attached  show how it supposed to be.

Comment: conerning "text in line" I showed you the solution. If you want the text to get smaller, you have to add smaller `font-size` settings to the media queries.